# trying to work through a list in sections

Tags: python

I have a list of lists sorted by the second value of the list (the groups).  I now need to iterate through this to work on each "group" at a time.  the data is `[name, group, data1, data2, data3, data4].`  I wasn't sure if I need a while or some other sort of loop, or maybe `groupby` but I've never used that.  any help would be appreciated.

```
for i in range (int(max_group)):
    x1 = []
    x2 = []
    x3 = []
    x4 = []
    if data[i][1] == i+1:
        x1.append(data[2])
        x2.append(data[3])
        x3.append(data[4])
        x4.append(data[5])
        print x1
        print 'next' # these are just to test where we're at
```

all the x's should have all the 3rd-5th column data (after the name and group number) of all the group 1 info. then i can use the group 1 info and move on to group 2.

Comment: btw, you can do:

x1 = x2 = x3 = x4 = []

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in sorted(set(group[1] for group in data)):
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = zip(*(group[2:] for group in data if group[1] == i))
```

*Note: this solution is quite inefficient, I'll bring a more efficient one in a minute!*

```
groups = {}
for d in data:
    try:
        groups[d[1]].append(d[2:])
    except AttributeError:
        groups[d[1]] = d[2:]

for i in sorted(j for j in groups):
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = zip(*groups[i])
```

*This is only slightly less ugly, but should work*

Comment: this is close, but not exactly what i needed.

Comment: oops.  accidentally hit enter.  all the x's should have all the 3rd-5th column data (after the name and group number) of all the group 1 info.  then i can use the group 1 info and move on to group 2.  

your black magic is good, but my description was weak.

Comment: is the edit of the snippet what you are looking for? Or do x1-x4 have to be lists with a single item?

Comment: x1 should be all the third column data that has a '1' in the second column.  x2 should be fourth and so on.  i will then use x1-x4 in the loop.  then the loop returns and x1 should be all the data with a '2' in the second column.  does that makes sense?  sorry if i'm not clear.

Comment: seems closer, but i guess i'm not being clear in my explanation.  i'll continue trying on my own.

Answer (score 0):

suppose list inside list is

```
mylist = [[name],[add],[data1],[data2]]
```

to iterate over each list inside list you should try the following code:

```
for each_list in mylist:
    if isinstance(each_list,list):
         #do something with that list inside list
```

Sorry if this answer doesnot matched your question.